# Hosting Office taskpane add-in manifest on webserver

Tags: ms-office, manifest, add-in

I've been able to make an Office Taskpane Add-In available within Word by placing the manifest XML file on a network folder. What I would like to do, however, is have the manifest file hosted on my webserver that hosts the Taskpane webapp as well and have Office grab the manifest from there.

I tried adding the URL to where the manifest file is hosted to the Trusted Web Add-In catalogs and I see it listed as a catalog of type "SharePoint" (while it's not a SharePoint site, just a regular old http host). My add-in also isn't showing up in Word.

Is there a way for me to host the manifest XML file on a regular webhost and have the add-in made available in Office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [side-load add-ins](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing) but it isn't recommended for production use. It makes updating the manifest rather tedious at any scale beyond 1or 2 users.

I recommend taking a look at [Publish your Office Add-in](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish). There are sever options beyond the network share method. For internal deployments

Comment: All links are dead today